# Citations not working in Sweave

Tags: bibliographies, citing, texlive, r, sweave

I am trying to run this [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) code in [R](http://www.r-project.org).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\section{Section}
I am citing \cite{ftest}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{ftest}http://www.mattblackwell.org/files/teaching/ftests.pdf
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Now, everything runs fine, but I'm getting the warnings:

```
Citation `ftest' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.
There were undefined references.
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

In the generated pdf, I get the references section and the referred link, but in the section, it shows:

```
"I am citing [?]."
```

My configuration is:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
- R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) -- "Masked Marvel"

PS:

1. I am new to LaTeX so please let me know if I can provide any additional information.
2. @Admins: I was not sure whether this is the right forum to post this, given that it is R specific, so please move it to the appropriate location.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: I ran your code (having commented out the `\SweaveOpts` line) and it worked fine for me. Note that you have to run LaTeX twice before the references show up properly.

Comment: I would also suggest switching to [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) which is more advanced than sweave.

Comment: Okay, this may be a [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) issue. I was actually using the 'Compile PDF' feature that it provides. It still gives the same error. I used knit2pdf of the knitr package and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an answer. It seems that you were able to answer your question.